# Print Issue in Google Crome and Firefox Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, printing

I am using print facility of browser using javascript. Here is , what i did till.

```
    BindPrintPubReport: function () {
            //Printed by Values.           
            var username = "Sanjeev";
            //End.
            var htmltags = '';
            htmltags += '<h3 style="margin: 10px 0 20px 10px; border-left: 3px solid #4e8ff7; font-size: 23px; padding: 0 10px;">Report Header</h3>';

            htmltags += '<div style="float:left;margin-right:88px;padding-left:10px;margin-top:-20px;">';
            htmltags += '<div><span style="width:120px;display:inline-block;">Generated By : </span>' + username + '</div>'

            //images or logo i want to add in report
            htmltags += '<div style="float:left;margin-right:88px;padding-left:10px;margin-top:-20px;"><img src=http://localhost:1122/images/logo_02.png"/></div>';

          //print document preparation
            var docprint = window.open("", "_blank");
            docprint.document.open();
            docprint.document.write('<html mozNoMarginBoxes><head>');
            docprint.document.write('<style>@page{ margin:45px 10px;}body{font-size:14px;}</style>');
            docprint.document.write('</head><body >'); 
            docprint.document.write(htmltags);
            docprint.document.write('</body></html>');

            //Start 
           docprint.focus();
           docprint.print();
           docprint.close();
           //end.

        }
```

Firstly i loaded, which work in google crome and firefox but in google crome image not loading. To load image in document, i replace the code,`

```
         //Start 
           docprint.focus();
           docprint.print();
           docprint.close();
           //end.
```

by,

```
//start
   docprint.document.write("<script>$(window).load(function(){       docprint.print();docprint.close(); });</script>");
            //end.
```

it make the image load in google crome, but printing did not work in Firefox. Printing is not behaving properly as i mentioned. What shall i do for support in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code:

```
 //Start 
 docprint.focus();
 docprint.print();
 docprint.close();
 //end.
```

to

```
  $(docprint).ready(function () {
                setTimeout(
                  function () {
                      docprint.focus();
                      docprint.print();
                      docprint.close();
                  }, (1000));
            });
```

That finally works with both Firefox and Google Chrome Browser.